# i have question! how to 'removeattr' next 'attr' "readonly"

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp

Text status is `readonly` now.
I want change remove `readonly` and modify and add `readonly`.

Code is operates when the button(modify) is `onClick`.
Code is

```
`$("input[name=ELEMENT]").removeAttr('readOnly');`
```

i want now text status is

```
'readonly' -> onClick(modify) -> removeAttr('readonly') -> modify ->attr('readonly')
```

how i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to control the actions on html components.

On top of my head, I think you can do is set a callback function when the input is out of focus. Something like this.

```
$("input[name=ELEMENT]").on('focusout', function(e){
        this.attr('readonly');
});
```

This can be a solution but you can also be as creative as you can with jQuery.

Hope this helps! Happy Coding :)

Comment: In a some hours i will going to home and try this. thank   b